# Flatten groups in CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to count the leagues available inside an `ObservableCollection`. The problem's that the league name is duplicated, so I need to remove the duplicates. Actually what I've is this:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Models.Event> _matches = new ObservableCollection<Models.Event>();

public ObservableCollection<Models.Event> Matches
{
    get { return _matches; }
}
```

Essentially I've a collection of events, now each event have a league associated. My idea is create another property called `LeaguesCount`:

```
public int LeaguesCount
{
   //remove duplicate record from _matches here
}
```

and return the leagues available, but there is another problem. Because each league is different, so I could have:

```
Premier League x3
Serie A x5
Super League x4
...
```

I need to get the count numer separated. Noticed that this league are associate in a nation name, so I could have in `_matches` two event with this structure:

*Event (1)*

```
match_name = 'Foo';
match_nation = 'England';
match_league = 'Premier League';
```

*Event (2)*

```
match_name = 'Test';
match_nation = 'England';
match_league = 'Premier League';
```

*Event (3)*

```
match_name = 'Another event';
match_nation = 'England';
match_league = 'Championship';
```

so how you can see in `England` nation are available three events with `Premier League` leagues name and `Championship` league name, I need to get from nation `England` the count of all leagues avoid of course the duplicate.

The structure of the event is basically this:

```
public class Event : ViewModel
{
     private string _matchNation,
                    _matchLeague,
                    _matchName;
}
```

Each fields have a property associated. The properties related to this question are:

```
public string MatchNation
    {
        get { return _matchNation; }
        set
        {
            _matchNation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string MatchLeague
    {
        get { return _matchLeague; }
        set
        {
            _matchLeague = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string MatchName
    {
        get { return _matchName; }
        set
        {
            _matchName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Result wanted:

```
England -> League count (2) [Championship, Premier League]
```

The main problem is the different nation name, because I bind the source in the xaml like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Matches}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchNation" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

and in the `GroupHeaderTemplate`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Orange" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

but the `ItemCount` actually return all the items count (event) and not the leagues without duplicated, that's an error.

Comment: I think you made either a typo or you have a logical issue. You are grouping by `MatchNation` -> There is only **England** so the outcome (3) is correct. You should group instead by `MatchLeague`

Comment: @lokusking is not a logical issue, I need to group the event for nation, so in my groupdescription I've this organization: `Nations->Leagues->Events`. Now I need to get the count of leagues (without duplicate) for all nations. I don't know what is unclear, let me know, I'll try to explain better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave me really a little bit headache on this.
Unfortunately, your Models are not in the shape to do this. I've modified them a bit (I was too lazy to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` everywhere):

**Models**

```
 public class Country {

        public Country() {
            this.Leagues = new ObservableCollection<League>();
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<League> Leagues { get; }

    }

    public class League {

        public League() {
            this.Events = new ObservableCollection<Event>();
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Event> Events { get; }
    }

    public class Event : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private string _matchName;
        public string MatchName {
            get { return _matchName; }
            set {
                _matchName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
```

**ViewModel with Demo-Data**

```
public partial class VM {

        public VM() {
            var eng = new Country() {Name = "England"};
            var l1 = new League() {Name = "Championship" };
            l1.Events.Add(new Event() {MatchName = "Another event" });
            var l2 = new League() { Name = "Premier League" };
            l2.Events.Add(new Event() { MatchName = "Foo" });
            l2.Events.Add(new Event() { MatchName = "Bar" });
            eng.Leagues.Add(l1);
            eng.Leagues.Add(l2);
            this.Countries.Add(eng);
            
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Country> _countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>();

        public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries {
            get { return _countries; }
        }

    }
```

**CollectionViewSource**

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Countries}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

**ListView**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel DataContext="{Binding Items}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                            <TextBlock Text="->" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="League count" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Leagues.Count}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Leagues}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Orange" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Leagues}">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

**Note**

As you can see, the Items displayed below your Groupheader can be modified (Marked in Yellow).
To do this, you have to change The `DataContext` of the Panels each time (Im quite sure, there is no other way).

**Closure**

Not pretty but working. You may have to play around with the XAML so it fits your needs

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This fix the problem I guess I actually tried the code. Of course I need to change a lot of logic inside my structure. Thanks again and sorry for headache :)

Comment: just a question: is possible set as propertygroupdescription the Leagues? The leagues are an observable collection in your new logic, how can I bind in the second propertygroupdescription the leagues?

Comment: @AgainMe Sure you can. But then the outcome might be different

Comment: I opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189278/how-to-bind-observable-collection-in-propertygroupdescription